# Is relation R isotone isomorphism with operation *

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, relations

I have follow operation $*$ defined like $MxM \rightarrow M$ where $M=\{a,b,c,d\}$

[image]

and relation $R=\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d),(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\}$

Decide, if $R$ is isotone  with operation $*$ on M.

**Solution**

I know definition of isotone isomorphism:

$(G,\leq ), (H, \preceq )$ are ordered set

$f: G \rightarrow H$

$\forall x,y \in G: x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$

But I don't know how to apply this rule.

**My guess**

I think, that from $R$ implies

$(a,a) \leq (a,b) \leq (a,c) \leq (b,b) \leq (b,c) \leq (c,c)$ and $(d,d)$

If I do map to $*$ operation a get:

$(a,a)\in R \rightarrow a\in M \\
(a,b)\in R \rightarrow b\in M \\
etc..$

I get:

$a \leq b \leq c \nleq a \leq d \leq a$

So, the answer is no, $R$ is not isotone isomorphism with M.

Please,is that good solution?
Or how should a solution looks like?

Comment: Do you want to prove that $*$ is an isotone map, relative to the partial ordering $R$? That is a question that makes sense (I didn't check if it is). In this case, it would be to prove that $*$ is isotone in each of its coordinates, but it couldn't, of course, be an isomorphism, since it is not bijective. As it stands, your question doesn't seem to make sense, as pointed out by StephenMeskin

Answer (score 1):

$R$ cannot be an isomorphism because it not a bijection, it is not even a function.

@amrsa $x\to x\star a $ is the identity map so it is an isotone isomorphism. Similarly for $x\to a\star x $.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But those are not the same as the original map, which is binary. Even if we wanted to prove that $*$ is isotone, what we would have to show was that for each $x_0$, the maps $x \mapsto x * x_0$ and $x \mapsto x_0 * x$ were isotone. Note also that for $x_0 \in \{c,d\}$, the maps are not bijective. I can't see how one could say $*$ is isotone because for some fixed $x_0$ the resulting maps are. But I agree with what you had in your answer and was just trying to check if the question had the concepts swapped.